# Nested array in JSONObject is returning as empty (org.json)

Tags: java, arrays, json, selenium

I am getting a nested JSON array ("invested") from within a JSON file, but the array appears to be empty when I try to use it.

My JSON file:

```
    {
"invested": [
    {
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "password" : "test"
    }
],
"notInvested": [
    {
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "password" : "test"
    }
]}
```

Here is how I get the JSONObject from file:

```
public JSONObject returnJSONObject(String path) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + path;
    
    JSONObject obj = parseJSONFile(path);

    return obj;
}

public static JSONObject parseJSONFile(String filename) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
    Reporter.log(content);
    return new JSONObject(content);
}
```

And here is where it fails. When I try to call 'loginPage.login(loginArray.get(0).toString(), loginArray.get(1).toString());';

```
JSONObject validLogins = returnJSONObject("valid-user-logins.json");
JSONArray loginArray = (JSONArray) validLogins.get("invested");

// submit valid credentials
loginPage.login(loginArray.get(0).toString(), loginArray.get(1).toString());
```

The error i get back when I run the program says that my index 0 is out of bounds for length 0:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.
```

I am quite new to JSON so this is all still a bit confusing, Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
For clarification, I am trying to grab the "email" & "password" from the "invested" array in the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not pulling the email and password out of the object within the JSON array correctly.

`loginArray` contains a JSON array, with one element in it, a JSON object.
`loginArray.get(0)` has the following value:

```json
{
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "password" : "test"
}
```

You are attempting to convert this entire object to a string, when you want to be pulling out the values of the individual properties within this object.

To obtain the email address, use `loginArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("email")`.  This gets the first element out of `loginArray` as a `JSONObject`, and then reads the value of the `email` property of this `JSONObject` as a string.

To obtain the password, use `loginArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("password")`.

Comment: Heythanks for the post, However I just tried what you suggested and have done this:

loginPage.login(loginArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("email"), loginArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("password"));

However I still get this error: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0.

Comment: @bway: I don't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` accessing these JSON values.  Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace: I suspect you have a separate problem with your `login()` method not related to accessing JSON values.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out somthing previously in my script was messing the error up. Your answer now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays in your sample file only contain one element each.

```
JSONArray investedArray = (JSONArray) validLogins.get("invested");
JSONArray notInvestedArray = (JSONArray) validLogins.get("notInvested");
```

JSON reminder:

```
object: { key : value, key : value, ... }
array:  [ value, value, ... ]
```

Your sample file is:

```
{ key : array, key : array }
```

or

```
{ key : [ object ], key : [ object ] }
```

Comment: One element each? Does the contents of "invested" (email & password) not count as array elements? If not how could I grab them from "invested"?

Comment: The value of the key 'invested' is an array containing 1 element (the single object between the square brackets). If there were more elements, they would be separated by commas.

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now. However I have changed my JSON to this: 

"invested": [ "test@test", "test123!"]

I still get the same error?